# Strange behavior of notifyListener

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a list which is fetched from the server but when we get outside of the fetching method the list is initialized to default. I have noticed that the problem is with the `notifyListeners()` as here: 
[Does notifyListeners() sometimes complete asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945722/does-notifylisteners-sometimes-complete-asynchronously)

Interestingly, inside the fetching method the the list is ok.

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Product> _loadedProducts = [];

  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    try {
      var response =
          await http.get(StoreServer.serverAddress + '/products.json');

      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      List<Product> extractedList = [];
      extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
        _loadedProducts.add(Product(
            id: key,
            imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
            title: value['title'],
            price: value['price'],
            description: value['description'],
            isFavorite: value['isFavorite']));
      });
      _loadedProducts = extractedList;
      notifyListeners();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (!isInit) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      test = Provider.of<Products>(context);
      test.fetchAndSetProducts().then((_) {
        print("fetched");
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          isInit = true;
        });
      });
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: I have suggestion for better pattern. rather than working around didChangeDependencies, we can call fetchAndSetProducts in Products constructor. see here https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_sqlite_api_provider/blob/master/lib/d_screen/1_auto_init/auto_init_screen.dart

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic error. Check my comments..!

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Product> _loadedProducts = [];

  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    try {
      var response =
          await http.get(StoreServer.serverAddress + '/products.json');

      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      List<Product> extractedList = []; // it is an empty list
      extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
        _loadedProducts.add(Product(    // you add elements to _loadedProducts 
            id: key,
            imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
            title: value['title'],
            price: value['price'],
            description: value['description'],
            isFavorite: value['isFavorite']));
      });
      _loadedProducts = extractedList; // you reassign _loadedProducts to the empty list "extractedList"
      notifyListeners();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Am I right? I think you have that error!